# Why does Typescript not narrow object keys to string

Tags: typescript

If I define a type like this:

```
type O = { [k: string]: any };
```

I would expect that keys in `O` would be narrowed to be of type `string`. However, if I define:

```
type KO = keyof O;
```

`KO` evaluates to `string|number`. Why is this? Didn't I explicitly narrow `O`'s keys to be `string`s by stating `[k:string]` in my definition of `O`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a `string` index, you automatically get the `number` indexer as well as stated in the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types-and-index-signatures):

> If you have a type with a `string` index signature, `keyof T` will be `string | number` (and not just string, since in JavaScript you can access an object property either by using `strings` (`object['42']`) or `numbers` (`object[42]`)).

Comment: I guess I'm confused. I understand that Javascript allows both numbers and strings as indexers, but isn't the whole point of adding a type system to specify and enforce constraints? Javascript is constantly trying to coerce objects to strings but that wouldn't be a rationale for having Typescript implicitly append `| string` to primitives.

Comment: @Mattia I think the point here is that `object['42']` and `object[42]` refer to the same location in the object, there is no difference between the two. So if you have an object with a string indexer you can always use string values that contain numbers in them .. so why not just allow the numbers to be used as is.

Comment: One reason not to allow it is that the `KO` type is widened by the compiler (despite me telling it otherwise) and can't be used in situations where the narrower `string` type is required.